# How to sort the columns of a matrix in order of some other vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

Say I have a vector `A` of item IDs:

```
A=[50936
   332680
   107430
   167940
   185820
   99732
   198490
   201250
   27626
   69375];
```

And I have a matrix `B` whose rows contains values of 8 parameters for each of the items in vector `A`:

```
B=[0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1    0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1
   1    0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1
   0    0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1];
```

So, column 1 in matrix `B` represents data of item in row 1 of vector `A`, column 2 in matrix `B` represents data of item in row 2 of vector `A`, and so on. However, I want matrix `B` to contain the information in a different order of items stored in vector `A2`:

```
A2=[185820
    198490
    69375
    167940
    99732
    332680
    27626
    107430
    50936
    201250];
```

How do I sort them, so that column 1 of matrix `B` contains data for item in row 1 of vector `A2`, column 2 of matrix `B` contains data for item in row 2 of vector `A2`, and so on?

My extremely crude solution to do this is the following:

```
A=A'; A2=A2';

for i=1:size(A,2)
    A(2:size(B,1)+1,i)=B(:,i);
end

A2(2:size(B,1)+1,:)=zeros(size(B,1),size(B,2));

for i=size(A2,2)
    for j=size(A,2)
        if A2(1,i)==A(1,j)
            A2(2:end,i)=A(2:end,j);
        end
    end
end

B2 = A2(2:end,:);
```

But I would like to know a cleaner, more elegant and less time consuming method to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution

You can use second output of `ismember` function.

```
[~ ,idx] = ismember(A2,A);
B2 = B(:,idx);
```

**Update**:I tested both my solution and another proposed by [hbaderts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4221706/hbaderts)

```
disp('-----ISMEMBER:-------')
tic
    [~,idx]=ismember(A2,A);
toc
disp('-----SORT:-----------')
tic
    [~,idx1] = sort(A);
    [~,idx2] = sort(A2);
    map = zeros(1,size(idx2));
    map(idx2) = idx1;
toc
```

Here is the result in Octave:

```
-----ISMEMBER:-------
Elapsed time is 0.00157714 seconds.
-----SORT:-----------
Elapsed time is 4.41074e-05 seconds.
```

**Conclusion**: the **sort** method is more efficient!

Comment: Whoa! This is a very cool solution too. Crisp, concise and to the point. As an aside, how do you remember how many outputs do all these umpteen number of functions have? And more importantly, how do you recall about them at the correct moment? :)

Comment: before I saw it in the documentation. however before answering the question I used `help ismember` in the command prompt and rechecked the documentation!

Comment: @Kristada673 answer updated you can accept another answer!

Comment: Wow, thanks for the interesting edit. I also tried it for random `A` and `A2` with 100000 elements each (`randperm(100000)`) and the results there are 0.32 sec vs. 0.21 sec. So the `sort` is still faster, but not by much. I don't mind if your answer stays the accepted answer - both solutions work well, and speed is not always the main criteria.

Comment: change position of idx `B2 = B( idx, :) ;`

Answer (score 4):

As both `A` and `A2` contain the exact same elements, just sorted differently, we can create a mapping from the `A`-sorting to the `A2`-sorting. For that, we run the [`sort`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) function on both and save indexes (which are the second output).

```
[~,idx1] = sort(A);
[~,idx2] = sort(A2);
```

Now, the first element in `idx1` corresponds to the first element in `idx2`, so `A(idx1(1))` is the same as `A2(idx2(1))` (which is 27626). To create a mapping `idx1 -> idx2`, we use matrix indexing as follows

```
map = zeros(size(idx2));
map(idx2) = idx1;
```

To sort `B` accordingly, all we need to do is

```
B2 = B(:, map);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[A2, sort_order] = sort(A);
B2 = B(:, sort_order)
```

MATLAB's sort function returns the order in which the items in A are sorted. You can use this to order the columns in B.

Comment: But this will sort the item IDs in ascending order and store in `A2`. This is not what I want to do. I already have `A2` in some meaningful predefined order.

Answer (score 0):

Transpose `B` so you can concatenate it with `A`:

```
C = [A B']
```

Now you have

```
C = [ 50936  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0;
     332680  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
     107430  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0;
     167940  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
     185820  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
      99732  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0;
     198490  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
     201250  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0;
      27626  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0;
      69375  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1];
```

You can now sort the rows of the matrix however you want. For example, to sort by ID in ascending order, use [`sortrows`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

```
C = sortrows(C)
```

To just swap rows around, use a permutation of `1:length(A)`:

```
C = C(perm, :)
```

where `perm` could be something like `[4 5 6 3 2 1 8 7 9 10]`.

This way, your information is all contained in one structure and the data is always correctly matched to the proper ID.